# Adding flags to my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

Run with `bash IProject.sh`

Want to add `bash -h IProject.sh`

With `-h` (human) I want it to print out more information.

My code is...

```
while getopts h name
do 
   case $name in
      h) humanOpt=1;;
   esac 
done

#TESTING HERE
echo "$humanOpt"    

if [[ ! -z $humanOpt]]; then
   human version
else
   computer version 
fi
```

However, I am only printing the statements in the else.. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could figure yourself with a bit trial and error

```
bash IProject.sh -h
```

does the job. But you need to fill in a bit more space for bash to breathe

```
if [[ ! -z $humanOpt ]]; then # here
```

. Your first guess `bash -h IProject.sh` adds -h as an option to the bash command itself, not to the `IProject.sh` call.

Comment: Oh man... the location of my -h caused me an hour hahah! And what do you mean give bash space to breathe?

Comment: As posted, you do not have a space before the `[[` and `]]`; you don't mention getting any syntax errors, so perhaps this was just a typo in the question.

Comment: @chepner yes you are correct it was a type I will edit my question